# font to display utf-8 in cmd console

Tags: mysql, utf-8, fonts, cmd, registry

Hiho,

I'm trying to get some Asian UTF-8 characters, which are read from a mysql database, to display properly in the command line prompt. I'll go through the steps I've gone through in case someone else is after the same thing...

1: First I made sure the database was encoded, and set the globals utf8

```
mysql> show variables like 'char%';
+--------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                                                   |
+--------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                                                    |
| character_set_connection | utf8                                                    |
| character_set_database   | utf8                                                    |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                                                  |
| character_set_results    | utf8                                                    |
| character_set_server     | utf8                                                    |
| character_set_system     | utf8                                                    |
```

After that I could compare entries in my tables, but they still weren't displayed properly.

2: In the properties of cmd, I noticed it was using code page 850, so I decided to see how change that and changed that before running mysql

```
cmd> chcp 65001
cmd> "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysql.exe" "--defaults-file=C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\my.ini" "-uroot" "-p" "--default-character-set=utf8"
```

3: After checking the font used by the command line, neither font available could display what I needed. [Unifont](http://unifoundry.com/unifont.html) is a fixed size font that seems to be able to though

And that's where I am now. After installing it; I just can't seem to be able to add the Unifont to the list of fonts in command prompt. I found [this tutorial](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/stupid-geek-tricks-enable-more-fonts-for-the-windows-command-prompt/) on registry editing to add it but no luck. The other available fonts were there though. Even replacing the current one just caused it to use the default font instead. It seems strange Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to hell. First off, the MySQL `utf8` datatype is **not utf8**, it's an unfortunately named-in-the-past datatype, when utf8 used fewer bytes. Today, you actually need [`utf8mb4`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html). As in, it's not optional, if you're dealing with unicode data, you *need* `utf8mb4`. And then: the windows console subsystem *cannot do unicode properly* so get a better console like Console2 or the like, because no amount of codepage fiddling is going to make this work properly with the "cmd" shell.

Answer (score 0):

The font in cmd needs to be Lucida Console.

[*More discussion*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#entering_accents_in_cmd).